# ASP.NET MVC 2: Data Annotation or Template: way to associate a DDL to its Model.data option list?

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

Summary:

If you use ASP.NET MVC 2's templates to render a DropDownList, how would you access the list of options if they are stored in the top level View's Model.property?  Also, is there some [DataAnnotation] way to associate this list?  Links to examples would be very helpful.

Background:

In ASP.NET MVC 2, you can create a custom class like `StateName` and use an EditorTemplate called `StateName.ascx`, which will display that partial view anytime it finds a `StateName` property.  Brad Wilson has a great write-up [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) describing it.  These partial view templates can be nested so that each template only deals with it's own scope (matching the template's scope to the matching POCO's properties).

Setup:

Now imagine that the `StateName.ascx` renders a DropDownList and needs the list of possible states ([{"AL","Alabama"},{"PA","Pennsylvania"},...]).  Generally, the top level View Model has all we need to render both the DomainModel (like our ShoppingCart), and any miscellaneous data like lists for drop downs.

Question:

**So, the question is how does a partial view template `StateName.ascx` reference the non-partial top level view's Model property `IList<StateName> States` to populate the DDL in the partial view template?** (especially if you have several nested or `deep dive` renderings like Model.Customer[0].BillingAddress.State, the template's parent view may not be the top level view).

Another angle may be to put some sort of [Data Annotation] on the class property that associates this list of possible states to the partial view template's Model?

For example, here's the top level View's Model:

```
Model.ShoppingCart.Customer.ShippingAddress;
Model.ShoppingCart.Customer.BillingAddress;
Model.StateNames;         // IList<StateName>
Model.MaritalStatusNames; // IList<MaritalStatus>
Model.GenderNames;        // IList<Gender>
```

Furthermore we could make all DDL data lists in one property, like `Model.DDLs.StateNames`, `Model.DDLs.GenderNames`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is that the partial template cannot access the parent's entire Model because it only receives the sub-model that it's meant to work with.

In your case (i.e. global lists of things that don't change) you could always declare your list in a static property on some helper object so that you don't need a model instance to be able to access it. For example your Address object could have a static list of all states.